# How to merge an entity with null List?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an `@Entity` with a `Set` that is `null` by default.
When initially creating the entity or updating it when it was fetched inside a `@Transactional` method, everything is ok.

BUT: when I try to merge a detached entity, I'm getting a `HibernateException`, even though I'm not touching the child `Set` at all:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
   private Set<ChildEntity> child = null; //by default

   public Set<ChildEntity> getChild() {
       if (child == null) {
           child = new LinkedHashSet<>();
       }
       return child;
   }
}
```

I can save the entity without having to initialize the child list:

```
@Transactional
public MyEntity create() {
    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
    //set some params (but not the child object)
    dao.save(entity);
    return entity; //OK though child=null
}
```

But the following merge fails:

```
MyEntity entity = service.create(); //see above
rsp = runLongTask();
updateSomeParams(entity, rsp); //not touching child
dao.merge(entity); //throws HibernateException
```

Result:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: MyEntity.child
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processDereferencedCollection(Collections.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processUnreachableCollection(Collections.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushCollections(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 33 more
```

Why can't I merge the entity with `null` Lists? How can I prevent the exception?

Comment: try this instead of null private 


`Set<ChildEntity> child = new HashSet<ChildEntity>();`

Comment: Yes that would work, *but* it would mean I have to initialize each and every Set in the entity explicit (there are multiple). Is it the correct way to achieve a `merge`, or am I just doing things wrong? Plus I thought it would already be sufficient to lazy init the collection in the `getter`, which I do for every `Set`.

Comment: Actually, Hibernate doesn't recommend to place any logic into setters/getters.

Comment: Well it's not logic, it's just a lazy collection initialization **if** the collection is accessed from code. But most of the time it is not, so it may remain `null`.

Answer (score 0):

since you create a new child (child = new LinkedHashSet<>();) everytime child is null can you try the following in the create method

```
@Transactional
public MyEntity create() {
    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
    //set some params (but not the child object)
    entity.getChild().clear(); //Remove all of the elements from this set 
    dao.save(entity);
    return entity; //OK though child=null
}
```

Basically, remove all the elements from the set if you are not going to set it

Comment: I don't want to clear the list always. Sometimes it is even populated with data. But not in all cases.

Comment: if you want to populate the list set the list, if not clear the list, write an if else statement